# PHP - what is character encoding to create new folder and files write in Arabic with Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php, character-encoding, mkdir, windows-server-2012-r2, iconv

I have problem when create new folder or upload new file in php with arabic language in windows server 2012 R2 but it work correctly in windows client (7,8)

This is the code

```
<?php
 $new_path1="Archiving/صادر";
          //when use this both lines folder create like image below 
         //$new_path=iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-6', $new_path1);
          $new_path = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1256', $new_path1);       
         mkdir($new_path, 0700);

 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: I read that `the Microsoft file system stores filenames as UTF-16` (I'm not sure about that), so try that.

Comment: you mean but UTF-16 insted of windows-125 $new_path = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $new_path1);

Comment: yeah, try that, but since `Archiving/` has been taken correctly, I doubt that's the problem (since utf-16 doesn't extends ascii like utf-8 or windows-1256 does). Have you the same problem without doing any conversion?

Comment: No doesn’t work

Comment: when do it in windows 7 or 8 it's work perfect like this `iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1256',`